# How to launch php script binded to different ip adresses?

Tags: php, freebsd

I’ve got ethernet interface on FreeBSD 7.1 with 3 ip adresses binded to it.

# ifconfig

```
em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
options=19b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4>
ether 00:e0:81:b1:1b:4b
inet 89.xx.xx.1 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 89.xx.xx.255
inet 89.xx.xx.2 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 89.xx.xx.2
inet 89.xx.xx.3 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 89.xx.xx.3
media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
status: active
```

How to launch php script binded to different ip adresses? I need this script to access one service from different ip addresses.

Comment: Are you talking about PHP streams or what? PHP itself doesn't bind to anything automatically..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set up a service at a specified IP-address, just fill in that address as the second parameter of the [socket_bind](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php) function. If the IP address is varying depending on the situation, you can use a command line parameter to specify this address

If you want the script to use a specified IP address when connecting to a remote service, that is not easy. Since the internet stack on your computer determines which IP address will be used, depending on which network the destination is. And in your case all IP addresses are on the same network.
I think that you you should think in this situation whether it is **really** required to use a particular address...

Comment: Binding to specific IP is very easy when connecting to a remote server. In case of the socket_* functions, you just need to call socket_bind before doing socket_connect (yes, socket_bind is not just for listening sockets). In case of HTTP stream wrappers and such (such as file_get_contents), they accept a context parameter which you can use to setup a context that binds to a specific IP address (see: http://fi.php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php)

Comment: Also curl_setopt may be used.

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");